# Monitor USB HID events?

Tags: macos, usb

I am looking for a way to monitor the raw USB HID events generated by devices such as keyboards, mice and other similar devices. There used to a IOUSBFamily kext with logging enabled that could be installed that would do this, but Apple hasn't updated it since OSX 10.9, so it doesn't seem to work anymore.

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: Fair enough, I do not a seek a software recommendation as such, but "how to do this". Should I rephrase the question or post a new one?

Comment: [edit] and rephrase the question.

Comment: Does Wireshark support this on macOS? I know it has USB monitoring on Windows and Linux.

Comment: Yes it's supported. You probably need nightly builds of wireshark. Haven't tested this yet, but read [here](https://aud-ios.com/2017/10/22/usb-monitoring-with-wireshark/).

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Little Flocker](https://www.littleflocker.com/) (monitors file access) and [Micro Snitch](https://www.obdev.at/products/microsnitch/index.html). I have both, as well as Little Snitch, which monitors network traffic. It can be quite confusing when all these messages pop up, sometimes ten in several seconds. Best is to try one, see how it works, get a feeling about it, then install another, etc.